# uncaughtException: navigator is not defined when running backand.init in node.js

Tags: backand

My node.js script calls `backand.init()` and I am getting an error while running the script.

```
error: uncaughtException: navigator is not defined
error: ReferenceError: navigator is not defined
    at Object.backand.init (node_modules/@backand/vanilla-sdk/dist/backand.js:1714:15)
```

I ran the script on mac terminal with node command.
I tested demo.js on backand/nodejs-sdk npm but the same error occurred.

Answer (score 1):

It was just fixed. Upgrade to latest nodejs SDK